# Swift - Hero animation to dismiss View

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I am having trouble using the **[Hero Library](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero)** to dismiss my `ViewController` with custom animation.

In the end I would like to have pretty much the exact same animation as in this video:

[preferred dismiss animation](https://streamable.com/8wxco)

So far my dismiss animation looks like this:

[my dismiss animation so far](https://streamable.com/1k7fj)

I am having 3 major problems which I can not figure out:

**1.**
When presenting/dismissing my `ViewController` there seems to be this white background behind my 2nd `ViewController` but I would like to just cover my first `ViewController` with the 2nd without any white views.

**2.**
My `image` disappears after the user starts swiping down behind my views when instead it should not change its position (*preferred dismiss animation*) until the view actually dismisses. Same things goes for the `add-Button` in the bottom right corner.

**3.** Like in the *preferred dismiss animation* my the `backgroundView`(lightGray View in the 2nd video) should dismiss a bit fast then the other `subviews`. I tried using the `cascade-modifier` but couldn't get that effect.

This is my 2nd `ViewController`:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.wishlistBackgroundView.hero.isEnabled = true
    self.wishlistBackgroundView.heroID = "wishlistView"

    self.wishlistBackgroundView.hero.modifiers = [.fade, .translate(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 800), z: 20)]

    // adding panGestureRecognizer
    panGR = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
              action: #selector(handlePan(gestureRecognizer:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(panGR)

    self.wishlistLabel.text = wishList.name
    self.wishlistImage.image = wishList.image
    self.theTableView.wishList = wishList.wishData
    self.theTableView.tableView.reloadData()


    view.addSubview(wishlistBackgroundView)
    view.addSubview(dismissWishlistViewButton)
    view.addSubview(menueButton)
    wishlistBackgroundView.addSubview(wishlistView)
    wishlistBackgroundView.addSubview(wishlistLabel)
    wishlistBackgroundView.addSubview(wishlistImage)
    wishlistView.addSubview(theTableView.tableView)
    wishlistView.addSubview(addWishButton)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([


        // constrain wishlistView
        wishlistBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        wishlistBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        wishlistBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        wishlistBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),


        wishlistView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 160.0),
        wishlistView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        wishlistView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        wishlistView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),

        // constrain wishTableView
        theTableView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.topAnchor, constant: 60.0),
        theTableView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        theTableView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0),
        theTableView.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30.0),

        // constrain dismissButton
        dismissWishlistViewButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        dismissWishlistViewButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 23.0),

        // constrain menueButton
        menueButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        menueButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -25.0),

        // constrain wishlistImage
        wishlistImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.topAnchor, constant: -70),
        wishlistImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
        wishlistImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
        wishlistImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),

        //constrain wishlistlabel
        wishlistLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.topAnchor, constant: -47),
        wishlistLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 100),

        addWishButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
        addWishButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -40),

    ])

    // set DeleteWishDelegate protocol for the table
    theTableView.deleteWishDelegate = self


}

// define a small helper function to add two CGPoints
func addCGPoints (left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
}

// handle swqipe down gesture
@objc private func handlePan(gestureRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    // calculate the progress based on how far the user moved
    let translation = panGR.translation(in: nil)
    let progress = translation.y / 2 / view.bounds.height

  switch panGR.state {
  case .began:
    // begin the transition as normal
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  case .changed:

    Hero.shared.update(progress)

    // update views' position based on the translation
    let viewPosition = CGPoint(x: wishlistBackgroundView.center.x, y: translation.y + wishlistBackgroundView.center.y)

    Hero.shared.apply(modifiers: [.position(viewPosition)], to: self.wishlistBackgroundView)


  default:
    // finish or cancel the transition based on the progress and user's touch velocity
       if progress + panGR.velocity(in: nil).y / view.bounds.height > 0.3 {
         Hero.shared.finish()
       } else {
         Hero.shared.cancel()
       }
  }
}
```

I couldn't find any good tutorials on this nor anything on these topics on git. If anyone knows even one answer to any of the problems I am more than happy.

Technically these are 3 questions but they are quite related. If this is against SO rules, I am happy to ask them separately.

Comment: remove the fade modifier from your second view controller for white background.

Comment: that didn't do anything :/

Comment: I just removed the `.fade` , if I remove the whole line the panGesture animation does not really work anymore. `backgroundView` does not move but instead just fades

Comment: Here is my git in case anyone would like to have a closer look at my project: https://github.com/chriskonnerth/Wishlist

Comment: Make sure that you have also enabled self.hero.isEnabled on the navigation controller if you are doing a push/pop inside the navigation controller.

Comment: I did that. It is not like the animation is not working at all. It is working. Just not the way I want it to. Another problem is that if I delete the `wishlistBackgroundView.hero.modifiers` there is a problem with dragging the view down. My `wishlsitBackgroundView` is not moving. But the animations do still work